# EF, postgres, unrecognized winsock error 10054

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, postgresql-12

I am writing a .NET app that uses Entity Framework to write data to a Postgres v12 database. The app itself watches the filesystem and writes data to the database every time it sees changes.

The data itself is both inserts and updates, spread across multiple tables.

This works so far - most of the time.

However, quite regularly the program simply hangs, it stops responding. It looks like the more data to write, the more often the problem occurs.

After restarting the app, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

The actual hanging happens when calling

```
DbContext.SaveChanges
```

Then in the Postgres log I find an entry:

> LOG: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
> LOG: incomplete message from client (Translated from German)
> LOG: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10054
> LOG: incomplete message from client

Google didn't help me with the message, there it's always about connection problems, if you program sockets yourself.

Does anyone have an idea how I can proceed here? Can I change something in the connection parameters to Postgres or where to start looking at?

The Postgres database itself runs on the same system as my app,
the stacktrace when it hangs:

```
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Nativ]       Annotated Frame
System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketPal.Receive(System.Net.Sockets.SafeSocketHandle handle, System.Span<byte> buffer, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags, out int bytesTransferred) Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
 System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags, out System.Net.Sockets.SocketError errorCode)    Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
 System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.Ensure.__EnsureLong|40_0(Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, int count, bool async, bool readingNotifications)   Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage.__ReadMessageLong|194_0(Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector connector, bool async, Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, bool readingNotifications, bool isReadingPrependedMessage)    Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(bool async, Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, bool readingNotifications)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(bool async, bool isConsuming, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior)   Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    System.Data.Common.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection)    Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.IUpdateEntry> entries)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.IUpdateEntry> entriesToSave) Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext _, bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.dll!Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<bool, int>(bool state, System.Func<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, bool, int> operation, System.Func<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, bool, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionResult<int>> verifySucceeded)  Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)   Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges() Unknown Non-user code. Skipped loading symbols.
>   SPCDataWriterWorker.dll!Promess.MeasurementResults.SPCDataWriterWorker.Globals.SaveDBChangesWithEvent(Promess.MeasurementResults.Model.ResultContext db, string sTablename) Line 56 C#  Symbols loaded.
```

Referenced packages:

- EF Core 5.0.7
- NodaTime 3.0.3
- Npqsql 5.0.6

`SaveDBChangesWithEvent` is just that:

```
internal static void SaveDBChangesWithEvent(ResultContext db, string sTablename)
{
    if (!db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled)
    {
        db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    }

    int iSavedRowCount = db.SaveChanges();
    Debug.Trace($"{iSavedRowCount} geänderte Datensätze in {sTablename}");
    Globals.FireProcessFileStep(string.Format(
        Texts.ProcessStepWriteDBChangeCount, iSavedRowCount, sTablename), Globals.EventsSeverity.Debug);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a network problem.

Comment: App and Postgres-Server are running on the same system. Tried several systems of Win7 and Win10

Comment: The other possibility is that the client suddenly dies without properly closing the database connection. That might lead to errors like that.

Comment: the last thing I call is DbContext.SaveChanges. After that the App dives into efcore, npgsql. So i'm not closing any connection. IF the commmands succeeds its rather fast so it's not a timeoutproblem as well

Comment: How is the DbContext created and most importantly, disposed? EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library (that's ADO.NET) or the database driver (NpgSqL). It doesn't even open a connection until it either needs to read data or *save* data in response to SaveChanges. Buggy asynchronous code (eg `async void`, non-awaited tasks) could result in orphaned DbContexts that could get disposed or garbage-collected in the middle of an operation

Comment: @suriel what does `Globals.SaveDBChangesWithEvent` do? What is `SPCDataWriterWorker` ? If this occurs frequently, it's almost certainly a coding bug that results in premature disposal of DbContext

Comment: Where does `ResultContext ` come from? And what's the point of `string sTablename` when you work with an ORM, ie objects? Any table names are already specified in the ORM's model

Comment: I edited the post and added SaveDBChangesWithEvent - it does not much of magic. The Table-name ist just for debugging purposes and not relevant anymore. Right now I don't update single Tables. Its the whole Model all the Time. Well, the main thing seems to be: I have to examine a bit more. Recently I updates the referenced packages EFCore (5.0.7 -> 5.0.17), NodaTime (3.0.3 -> 3.1.9), Npgsql (5.0.5 -> 5.0.17) and after some Tests the Crash did not appear. I will have a closer look at it

Comment: @suriel there's no code that actually adds or modifies objects or creates the context in the new code. Please post enough code so people can understand what the application code does and reproduce the problem. This is neither an NpgSQL nor an EF Core issue. `SaveDBChangesWithEvent` points to a major bug - disabling change tracking even though you intend to *save* objects. EF Core is used in unconventional ways and probably uses antipatterns like a "repository" over the Unit-of-Work. We can't guess what else is going on.

Comment: My bet is still that whatever calls `SaveDBChangesWithEvent` dies suddenly, either because of an `async void` call or a fire-and-forget task that's not getting awaited.

Comment: There is not a single async in my code. Disabling ChangeTracking in the DBContext is because there is are lots of Update-/Insert-Operations happening and I only need to Track them Just before Writing. However: the if around DetectChanges is because I can disable this behavior via  config-switch. This does not affect the error at all. I honestly cant post the complete program but when the errors reappears I will try to boil down some real code and post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really looks like the error is gone after updating the referenced packages.
I will examine it further and post a more complete example once it happens again.
Thanks to all of you